# Append delete list's first element

Tags: python, list

I am trying to sort a list of tuple (each tuple consist of a word and number of occurrence ) by number of occurrence first and by alphabetical order if the number of occurrence is the same, but i can't figure it out what is going on with the tmp list here, i have tried to add a print line whenever a code line change the tmp[] but i still not get it.

The input is the following text:

```
hi
hi
what is your name
my name is bond
james bond
my name is damme
van damme
claude van damme
jean claude van damme
```

my code is

```
text = []
#taking each input line
while True:
    try:
        text.append(input())
    except:
        break

no = []
for i in range(len(text)):
    no.extend(text[i].split())

co = dict()
for word in no:
    co[word] = co.get(word,0) + 1
#sort by occurence
co = sorted(co.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
fin = []

tmp = [("abc", 3)]   #a dummy element for testing purpose
#sort by alphabetical order if similar occurrence
for i in range(1, len(co)):
    
    if i == len(co) - 1:
        if co[i][1] == co[i-1][1]:
            tmp.append(co[i])
            fin.extend(list(sorted(tmp,key= lambda x:x[0])))
            break
        if co[i][1] != co[i-1][1]:
            fin.append(co[i])
            break
    #compare current value with the previous one and the next one
    elif co[i][1] == co[i-1][1] and co[i][1] == co[i+1][1]:
        tmp.append(co[i])
        print(i, tmp)
        #there should be a output line with i = 1 and tmp =[("abc", 3), ("is", 3)] here 
    elif co[i][1] == co[i-1][1] and co[i][1] != co[i+1][1]:
        tmp.append(co[i])
        fin.extend(list(sorted(tmp,key= lambda x:x[0])))
        
        
    elif co[i][1] != co[i-1][1] and co[i][1] == co[i+1][1]:
        tmp = [co[i]]
        
    elif co[i][1] != co[i-1][1] and co[i][1] != co[i+1][1]:
        fin.append(co[i])
        
print(fin)
```

here is the output i got:

```
2 [('is', 3), ('name', 3)]
5 [('hi', 2), ('my', 2)]
6 [('hi', 2), ('my', 2), ('bond', 2)]
9 [('what', 1), ('your', 1)]
10 [('what', 1), ('your', 1), ('james', 1)]
[('is', 3), ('name', 3), ('van', 3), ('bond', 2), ('claude', 2), ('hi', 2), ('my', 2), ('james', 1), ('jean', 1), ('what', 1), ('your', 1)]
```

can someone explain to me where the ("abc", 3) went and why the output only prints when there has already been 2 elements in the tmp (line 1 of the output) but not immediately when i = 1 and the list is appended ("is", 3) ?

Answer (score -1):

You just need a better key function.

```
co = sorted(co.items(), key=lambda x:(-x[1], co))
```

The trick of "reversing" the sort on the occurrence count by using the inverse only works for numbers. In general, more complicated sorts can be used by defining a *comparison* function, and using `functools.cmp_to_key` to convert the comparison function to a key function. For example,

```
from functools import cmp_to_key


def compare(x, y):
    if x[0] < y[0]:
        return 1
    elif x[0] > y[0]:
        return -1
    elif x[1] < y[1]:
        return -1
    elif x[1] > y[1]:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
       

co = sorted(co.items(), key=cmp_to_key(compare))
```

---

(In Python 2, a `cmp` function was built-in, which mean `compare` above could more simply be defined as

```
def compare(x, y):
    return cmp(y[0], x[0]) or cmp(x[1], y[1])
```

This is the definition I had in mind that led to an error in the previous version of `compare` shown above.)

Comment: `compare(x,y)` would need to always equal `-compare(y,x)` for a meaningful comparison. But consider the case where `x=(5, 'a'); y=(5, 'b')`. `int(compare(x,y)) == 1`, but `int(compare(y,x)) == 0`.

Comment: Right, I do this a lot when trying to implement `compare` on the fly, since I miss the `cmp` function that used to be built in to Python.